# Can't Change power_method 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ati, bash, permissions, radeon

I am trying to modify my power method for my ati card as it's like having a helicopter in the room. I use the same methods described [here](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/).

```
sudo bash -c echo "profile" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
bash: /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method: Permission denied
```

I also tried to switch to root `sudo -i` and do the same but not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The redirection operator is not part of your `sudo` command. In other words, when you execute `sudo bash -c echo "profile" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method`, what actually happens is:

1. The shell executes `sudo bash -c echo "profile"`
2. `sudo`, which has the setuid bit set, asks for your password, and forks the process `bash -c echo "profile"` with EUID set to 0 (i.e., the command is executed as root)
3. The `bash` command executes `echo "profile"` and prints `profile` to standard output as root.
4. `bash` terminates, `sudo` terminates
5. The shell running your original command takes the string from standard output and tries to redirect it to `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method`, which gets you a `Permission denied` since the shell is not running with root privileges.

There are a number of ways to solve this. One is to give the entire string *with the redirection operator* as argument to `bash -c`:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "profile" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method'
```

I've also often seen people use `tee`, which looks somewhat nicer (and doesn't execute the `echo` command as root):

```
echo "profile" | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method
```

`tee` reads from standard input and outputs that to *both* standard output and *all* files you passed it as parameters.

Comment: No both doesn't work. I get `bash: line 0: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Comment: Ah, but that's probably a driver thing now. Both methods do work, and you are now allowed to write to `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method`. However, you can't just write anything arbitrary to that file. Looking at the [Xorg radeon KMS Power Management Options](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/#index3h2), I can successfully write the words `dynpm` and `profile` to `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method'`, but if I try to write `dpm` into the file I get the same error as you do. Maybe your driver doesn't support `profile`. What card are you running? I'm on a Radeon HD 6950.

Comment: I have Radeon HD 3650